# Need to file Income Tax Return

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, withholding

If my total tax is remitted as withholding tax should I still file income tax return?

Comment: I do not want deductions .

Comment: I am not engaged in any bussiness currently but if I do I will fill up W 8 BEN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you still need to file a return (provided you meed the income threshold and other requirements) even if you don't expect to get a refund back. The reason is that withholdings are just *estimates* of what you will actually owe in tax, and are rarely completely accurate. Your actual tax is computed by the final return. The return will show if you under-withheld and owe more tax, or over-withheld and get a refund.

Income tax is not like sales tax that is computed on-the-spot. It is based on the entire year's activity. Withholding just looks at your current period's income, extrapolates it out to a year and guesses at what your total tax will be (based on annual income, deduction status, etc.), and then computes the portion of that tax for the current period. It does *not* know things like whether or not you itemize, are eligible for credits, etc. so it's often imprecise.

Comment: Even if I am non residential alien and filed W 8 BEN .

Comment: If I earn by selling purchases through google from another country and  my sales are from outside USA .(App  ot released in US

Comment: @compenthusiast yes.

Comment: Do I still need     to physically mail   1040 NR to IRS.

Comment: OK               I understood.

Comment: One last thing do   what will happen if I don't.

Comment: As I said, if you are not exempt from filing for some reason then you should file. I'm not an expert on non-res requirements to know if you should file or not, but you can't not file just because you think your withholdings will cover your tax bill.  If you owed tax, there would be a penalty for not filing.  If you are due a refund, there is no penalty but if you wait too long you won't ever get your refund.

Comment: In this link  -> https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxation-of-nonresident-aliens

Comment: Doesn't A-2 mean that I am not liable.